# Interrogation about a gruntjs globbing pattern

Tags: gruntjs, glob

I would like to better understand the following **gruntjs globbing pattern**:

```
dist/resources/js/{,*/}*.js'
```

According to the documentation:

> `{}` allows for a comma-separated list of "or" expressions

My specific question is about this part: `{,*/}`. What does it mean? Why is there nothing before the first comma in the curly brackets?

Comment: Where did you see that pattern? Was it in some documentation? The only thing I can think of is that since the `{ }` syntax requires a comma-separated list, maybe there has to be at least one comma in it, even if it's not used?

Comment: @jakerella this snippet is taken from a codebase I am working on. I was probably copied and pasted into our codebase...